# Why is HpBandSterSearchCV (hpbandster-sklearn) returning Nan scores on future iterations?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am using the hpbandster-sklearn package to apply hyperband tuning to an xgboost.

In some cases the first iteration will see a score and the parameters move on. Only for the next iteration to produce a Nan score, even though all else is the same but the model sees more data. I am not sure why this is happening, and in my mind should be impossible as nothing has really changed between iterations.

Below is some code to produce an example. Many of the first iterations scores are Nan, but those that proceed onto the next are all Nan despite the respective first runs producing scores. I think this leads to essentially a random set of parameters to proceed and be named best?

Any explanation of this behaviour and issues in my understanding/method?

```
from sklearn import datasets
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from hpbandster_sklearn import HpBandSterSearchCV
import ConfigSpace as CS
from ConfigSpace import ConfigurationSpace, Integer, Float
import pandas as pd

X, y = datasets.load_breast_cancer(return_X_y = True, as_frame = True)

xgb = XGBClassifier(
    eval_metric = ['map','logloss','auc'],
    objective = 'binary:logistic',
    n_jobs = -1,
    verbosity = 0
)

params = ConfigurationSpace(seed=16069)
params.add_hyperparameter(Float('learning_rate', (0.1, 0.3), log=True))
params.add_hyperparameter(Integer('n_estimators', (100, 200)))

search = HpBandSterSearchCV(xgb, 
                            params,
                            optimizer = 'hyperband',
                            random_state = 65,
                            n_jobs = -1, 
                            n_iter = 3,
                            cv = 5,
                            verbose = 0,
                            resource_name = 'n_samples',
                            return_train_score = True,
                            scoring = 'neg_log_loss',
                            resource_type = float,
                            min_budget = 0.11)
search.fit(X, y)

pd.DataFrame(search.cv_results_)
```

[Table of Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKBFi.png)

I have tried a wide variety of different cross folds, random states, scoring metrics etc and this seems to be a prevailing issue, along with the amount of Nan scores produced in the first iteration also (on a much much larger data set).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that sometimes `y` contains only a single class after `min_budget` it applied. When CV splits it, you end up with some splits that only have one label, resulting in a NaN for that split. Try either increasing the `min_budget` until the error goes away, or alternatively reduce the number of CV folds (e.g. `cv=3`) to make the splits larger.

Comment: I thought this was the case at first as well but that wouldn't explain why increasing the number of rows then results in a Nan. The above model is given 190 rows in the second iteration with a roughly 60/40 of 1 to 0. The likelihood of ending up with only a single class is tiny. I've seen this same behaviour when using data and a budget where ending up with a unique class is essentially impossible.

Comment: Consider trying it with `sklearn.model_selection.HalvingRandomSearchCV`, setting `min_resources='exhaust'` vs. `min_resources='smallest'`. That may help indicate whether it's a resource allocation issue or not.